# Stopping httpd causes a process started from perl CGI script to receive SIGTERM

Tags: perl, apache, unix, cgi, signals

I am running a shell script from a perl CGI script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $command = "./script.sh &";
my $pid = fork();
if (defined($pid) && $pid==0) {
        # background process
        system( $command );
}
```

The shell script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap 'echo trapped' 15
tail -f test.log
```

When I run the CGI script from browser, and then stop httpd using `/etc/init.d/httpd stop`, the script receives a SIGTERM signal.

I was expecting the script to run as a separate process and not be tied in anyway to httpd. Though I can trap the SIGTERM, I would like to understand why the script is receiving SIGTERM at all.

What wrong am I doing here? I am running RHEL 5.8 and Apache HTTP server 2.4.

Thanks,
Pranav

Comment: What are you going to achive with this? Maybe a better way to do that.

Comment: Well, the script that I have written is just a dummy one. The actual script is supposed to run a process which is fairly long and as part of this process, it needs to shutdown httpd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process you are spawning still has httpd's parent PID attached to it. So this might work:

```
use POSIX qw / setsid /;
...
my $command = "./script.sh";
my $pid = fork();
if (defined $pid && $pid == 0) {
    close *STDIN;
    close *STDOUT;
    close *STDERR;
    setsid;
    system( $command );
    exit 0;
}
```

And since it doesn't sound like your process should ever return back to your script, you might even do

```
use POSIX qw / setsid /;
...
my $command = "./script.sh";
my $pid = fork();
if (defined $pid && $pid == 0) {
    close *STDIN;
    close *STDOUT;
    close *STDERR;
    setsid;
    exec( $command );
}
```